# How to overwrite a style from a partial "_shadows.scss" file to show box-shadows in ComboBox and DateEdit buttons only?

Tags: html, css, sass, devexpress

I had some ComboBox and DateEdit fields with very nice box-shadows

[image: Shadows before update]

Since updating DevExpress to 21.2.5, though, the box-shadows for the buttons have disappeared

[image: Shadows after update]

I looked at the button through Chrome Dev Tools, went to Styles, and filtered for "shadow." I found

```css
.shadow-none {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

in the file `_shadows.scss` line 6. Sure enough, unchecking it gave me the desired result. I clicked the link and was redirected to the file in Sources. It read

```css
// stylelint-disable declaration-no-important

.shadow-sm { box-shadow: $box-shadow-sm !important; }
.shadow { box-shadow: $box-shadow !important; }
.shadow-lg { box-shadow: $box-shadow-lg !important; }
.shadow-none { box-shadow: none !important; }
```

I've searched high and low for `_shadows.scss`, and regardless, editing it might cause undesirable results elsewhere. I tried my own CSS and even used `!important,` but none of the following code worked

Overriding `.shadow-none`

```css
.shadow-none{
    box-shadow: inset -10px -10px black !important;
}
```

Editing my own rule

```css
.cmbStatus .btn {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px $combobox_shadow_dark, inset -2px -2px 
    $combobox_shadow_light !important;
}
```

I'm not sure what I should try next. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That underscore scss file is a "partial" file in Sass. Check out https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4 for more info, as well as https://dev.to/sarah_chima/using-sass-partials-7mh, to learn how they work and how to modify them.

Comment: @TylerH I double-checked my styles.scss file, and '@import "shadows";' is not there. Thanks though!